# How to build or compile VS2010/XNA4 projects with vim?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, vim

I've played with a few different plugins to get C# to compile in vim, namely [Visual_studio.vim](http://www.plan10.com/vim/visual-studio/doc/1.2/),
 [vim-csharp](https://github.com/xandox/vim-csharp) and [vim-csharp](https://github.com/OrangeT/vim-csharp), but the only one that even starts
to compile is OrangeT's [vim-csharp](https://github.com/OrangeT/vim-csharp), but when I'm working on an XNA solution, all
the XNA references are not found:

```
The type or namespace name 'Xna' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

Is there anything I can do to better work with C#/XNA with vim?

If it's relevant: `Windows7x64bit VisualStudio2010 XNA4 Python2.7x64bit gVim73`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on Windows, so you always have the option to build on the commandline with msbuild. I'm sure you have the facility in vim to run a macro specifying a project relative to the current buffer's path.

The command line looks like

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\(version)\msbuild.exe "project file path"
```

This should pull in your project's references when building, so you'll avoid those errors.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I had also tried that (using cygwin, if that's relevant), and let it run for a minute or two and nothing seemed to happen, while it only takes a second in VS10. Had to kill the  process.

Comment: so to clarify, you were using vim within cygwin?

Comment: Scratch that, tried it again in cmd.exe this time instead and it seemed to work. No, using gVim, but wanted to use cygwin for commandline stuff here. Happened to have it open is all. Just give me a moment to set this up properly and I'll accept your answer.

Comment: getting an error using it from vim: `MSBUILD : error MSB1008: Only one project can be specified.
Switch: Studio` edit: Ah, needed quotes since my path had a space in it.

Comment: There we go :) strings with spaces will get you every time.

Answer (score 3):

@Reacher Gilt had the right idea, and so I want to give him the answer, but my final solution was to use the `msbuild.exe` which I've added to my `PATH` at some point, and combine it with [this solution](http://www.kevinberridge.com/2008/09/vim-c-compiling.html) to make a build.bat file and `:make` from that.

1. in my `*.sln` folder I wrote a `build.bat` file that looks like: `msbuild.exe "C:\path\to\*.sln"`
2. `set makeprg=build.bat`
3. **OR** `let &makeprg='"C:\path with spaces\build.bat"'`  if you've got spaces in the file path. That's `let` not `set` with an apostrophe and then a double quote surrounding the path, along with no slashes before the space characters.
4. `set errorformat=\ %#%f(%l\\\,%c):\ %m`   to format the error messages.
5. `:make` on a file inside that directory
6. `:cl` to list all the errors.

edit: I'm not sure why, but putting the `&makeprg` in your vimrc doesn't seem to do anything. Hopefully someone can explain it to me. You have to "manually" enter it in: `yy` switch to current file `<C-R>0<Bksp><CR>`

Comment: I wonder if you could write a vim script that would search the parent directory (or relevant path...) and set the makeprg automatically. It'd save you from making build.bats for each new solution you write.